# Using Task in OnNavigatedFrom() method (in View)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

The following method is called when navigating from a page in Windows Phone 8 app. Will the user experience benefit from the second option?

**Option 1**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     //work with UI
     Image.Source = null;
     //....
}
```

**Option 2**

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           //work with UI
           Image.Source = null;
           //....
        });
    });
}
```

Does it make sense to create the `Task` that all work do on the UI thread?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you notice if it was better? You should use a performance profiler to make optimizations. Otherwise, you are guessing.

Comment: Visually there is no difference. Theoretically, the second option is to improve performance. But we work with UI, and must switch to UI thread. It confuses me. Does it make sense to create a task that all work do on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

if your app is doing some background activities (like web request) before OnNavigatedFrom then you need to use UI thread to avoid Cross thread exceptions ,otherwise if only navigation is done then no need of UI thread.wherever necessary,absolutely no need to create task just Dispatcher is going to work.